# Diferença entre datas/horas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou precisando calcular a diferença entre duas datas em python, mas sempre da algum erro.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> data1 = datetime(2015, 8, 5, 8, 12, 23)
>>> data2 = datetime(2015, 8, 9, 6, 13, 23)
>>> difdata = data2 - data1
>>> '{0}:{2}'.format(*str(difdata).split())
'3:22:01:00'
```

quero fazer assim, mas quando tento abrir em outros sistemas da erro, quero criar um timestamp com as datas mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Está funcionando mas em outros sistemas não está? Que sistemas são esses? Explique melhor, quais erros estão aparecendo, desse jeito fica difícil alguém ajudar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você subtrai datas no formato `datetime` é retornado um objeto `timedelta` que tem um método `total_seconds()` que te dá os segundos totais:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '2015/08/05 08:12:23'
t = '2015/08/09 08:13:23'
f = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
dif = (datetime.strptime(t, f) - datetime.strptime(s, f)).total_seconds()
print(dif)
```

Answer (score 4):

Achei uma solução pesquisando a função DATETIME

```
s = '2015/08/05 08:12:23'
t = '2015/08/09 08:13:23'

date1 = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime("%s"))
date2 = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime("%s"))

difdate = date2 - date1

print(difdate)
```

Assim fica fácil transformar e calcular qualquer diferença.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizando a biblioteca **[dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/)**.

Dessa forma podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

a = "2015-08-05 08:12:23"
b = "2015-08-09 08:12:23"
f = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

ini = datetime.strptime(a, f)
fim = datetime.strptime(b, f)

di = abs(relativedelta(ini, fim))

print(f'{di.years} anos, {di.months} meses, {di.days} dias, {di.hours} horas, '
      f'{di.minutes} minutos e {di.seconds} segundos.')
```

Observe que o código recebe duas datas e horas no tipo **string**, as converte em  objetos **datetime**, e depois - com ajuda do método **[relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)** - calcula a diferença.

Observe também que o resultado deste método consiste em uma tupla, com a qual podemos, posteriormente, recuperar cada um de seus elementos.

O resultado do **print()** nada mais é do que os valores de cada elemento da tupla gerada anteriormente.